# How to fetch API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api

I have written a javascript to fetch API but it is not working can anyone please see that is there any error in my javascript. I have given some parts of my javascript which I think has error.

***MY JAVASCRIPT***

```
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.status}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

//Fetch API
const retrieveAllStatus = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

 
  // here we are making a network call to your api
  const response = await fetch('https://goodman456.000webhostapp.com/api.php');
  
  // then converting it to json instead of a readable stream
  const data = await response.json();

  // finally go over the array and return new object with renamed key
  const results = data.map(val => ({val.status}));

  return results;
}
```

Please just once visit the link below. It's my request.
https://goodman456.000webhostapp.com/api.php

I would make your work easy, My friends said that the below section

```
contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.status}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};
```

Especially the `{$record.status}` where I need the JSON data to be placed. My friend also said that there is something wrong in fetching API.

Please I have stucked here for a long time. And thanks in advance for those who answer this question.

Comment: Should post what error message you are running into.

Comment: Is `goodman456.000webhostapp.com` the domain of the client?

Comment: Improper destructuring assignment. `const results = data.map(val => ({val.status}));` should be like `const results = data.map(({status})=>({[status]: status});`.

Comment: Ok @StackSlave but what should I do here `{$record.status}`

Comment: You mean your `${record.status}`? That's not Destructuring, it's how you concatenate in a Template Literal. That just accesses `record.status` and puts it into that Template Literal.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Am not getting quotes

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't understand the question and there doesn't appear to be a [mcve]. For starters, `retrieveAllStatus` is never actually called. Please show all relevant code. Thanks.